# invoking base constructor in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I used virtual inheritance to solve the diamond inheritance problem. The problem is that I have to invoke the base class non-empty constructor in every sub-classes after the branching. Is there a way to avoid this situation?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {}
    Base(const double& V) : mV(V)
    {}
    const double& V() const {return mV;}
private:
    double mV;
};

class Child1 : virtual public Base
{
public:
    Child1(const double& V) : Base(V)
    {}
};

class Child2 : virtual public Base
{
public:
    Child2(const double& V) : Base(V)
    {}
};

class GrandChild : public Child1, public Child2
{
public:
    GrandChild(const double& V) : Child1(V), Child2(V)
    , Base(V) // IMPORTANT: this is needed to invoke the Base non-empty constructor
    {}
    void print() const
    {
       std::cout << this->V() << std::endl;
    }
};

class GrandGrandChild : public GrandChild
{
public:
    GrandGrandChild(const double& V) : GrandChild(V)
    , Base(V) // IMPORTANT: this is needed to invoke the Base non-empty constructor
    {}
};

class GrandGrandGrandChild : public GrandGrandChild
{
public:
    GrandGrandGrandChild(const double& V) : GrandGrandChild(V)
    , Base(V) // IMPORTANT: this is needed to invoke the Base non-empty constructor
    {}
};
```

Comment: If there existed a way, it would be the standard way of doing virtual inheritance.

Comment: The short answer is no.  That's part of why virtual bases must be used sparingly.  In your example, consider carefully if `Child1` and `Child2` should be members of `GrandChild` (or rationalised as two instances of another class named `Child`) rather than base classes.  Inheritance generally works better for "is-a" relationship (public inheritance) or "implemented in terms of" relationship (private or protected inheritance)  than for containment relationships (better represented as a member) or associations between classes (better represented as a pointer or reference member)

Comment: @Peter this is just a reproduction of an issue in a larger, more complicated code. Child1 and Child2 are supposed to be parent classes of GrandChild.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I agreed that the virtual inheritance base class invoke shall be for GrandChild. But subsequent classes should not need to do that because they are inherited directly from GrandChild.

Comment: @kstn -- the **most derived class** constructs the virtual base. So classes derived from `GrandChild` still have to construct `Base`, even if there is no further multiple inheritance.

Comment: They "should not" but they do, and there's very little we can do about it.